# Does 15dp represent the same physical size (say 7millimeters on screen) in every device? (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, dpi, screen-size

I found many definitions for 'dp' among the answers, but none of these answered this exact question.

It is said 'dp' is dpi independent.

So if you draw a line of 50dp programatically in your app and measure its actual size using a ruler(a tangible plastic ruler) and do this in 10 different devices with different screen sizes you will get the same length on the ruler?

Comment: In case you needed physically same dimensions, you're free to use `7mm` or `1in`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On 10 different devices with different configurations, will I get the same length on the ruler with a 50dp line drawn?

**Simplest answer, NO**

**However, it is very close!** And that is all that matters.

For a `48 x 48 dp` touch target...
Physical size on any device will be a square of size `9 ± 2mm`

Check out this link from Google: https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size